# Firebase Storage StorageTask Class Raw use of parameterized class 'StorageTask'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I have declared a StorageTask in my fragment and I am getting a lint Raw use of parameterized class 'StorageTask', how can I declare the StorageTask without Raw use

Below is how I have declared the StorageTask

```
private StorageTask storageTask;
```

Below is the full link error

```
public abstract class StorageTask extends ControllableTask <ResultT extends StorageTask.ProvideError > 
 

Known Direct Subclasses
FileDownloadTask , StreamDownloadTask , UploadTask 
FileDownloadTask 
A task that downloads bytes of a GCS blob to a specified File. 
StreamDownloadTask 
A task that downloads bytes of a GCS blob. 
UploadTask 
A controllable task that uploads and fires events for success, progress, and failure. 
A controllable Task that has a synchronized state machine.
 
 
  Gradle: com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0@aar
`StorageTask` on localhost
```

Comment: Where are you getting that "error"?

Comment: @Alex Mamo i am not getting any error its just a warning lint and i don't like warning lints

Comment: Have you tried to let Android Studio help you with that?

Comment: @AlexMamo yeah i have tried but its still bringing the lint i have tried changing the access modifier to public as Android studio suggested but the lint is still there

Answer (score 0):

If Android Studio doesn't help, then please add the following annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
```

Right before your class declaration.